# How to find the fraction of light absorbed by a surface?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction, absorption

How to find the fraction of light absorbed by a surface? What values do we need?

I am trying to find the fraction of light absorbed by a surface when it's dry and when it's wet.

I have something like these two but these do not really help me. I am a high school student and it would be great if it was explained clearly.

"The value of $a_d$ (absorption when dry)  is in  principle determined by  the complex refractive index  $n_r + in_s$ of the material, and by the roughness of the  surface (which influences the average angle  of incidence on  its randomly oriented facets, and the probability of multiple interactions, as in a crevice)."

and

"The  value of $a$, is in addition a function of $n_j$, the refractive index of the liquid film covering it. For the purpose of comparing the albedos $1 - a_d$ and 1-A of the dry and wetted surfaces, we estimate $a$,  in terms of $a_d$,  $n_l$, and $n_r$ as follows."

[Source and the question I am trying to understand](https://sci-hub.si/10.1364/AO.27.001278)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the website. You should probably be much more specific in order for us to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: @RedGiant I just updated the question, I hope it makes difference, but I can say this is the case. Thank you for warning and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand in those quotations? There's quite a lot of content, and it might be better if you narrow it down to something more specific.